QCanBus и Matapho(chai-2.14.0) - не инициализируется порт
Пытаюсь подключиться к can-порту через свое приложение. Но не получается инициализировать порт.
Вот код:
mDevice = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice( 
QStringLiteral("что тут писать не понимаю изначало стаяло socketcan"), QStringLiteral("канал должен быть 0"), &errorstring);

Этот метод возвращает null, не могу понять, либо я ставлю неправильные обозначения, любо qt не видит плагины, и как тогда сделать, чтобы qt работал с chai-2.14.
P.S. Через их софт CanVise порт рабочий, и получает данные.

Пример работы устанавливается вместе с Qt. (для открытия в qt creator "Начало"->"примеры", поиск "can bus")
